# How can I copy the contents of an opened TextMate document to the clipboard with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, textmate, applescript-objc

I need to copy the contents of an open TextMate document to the clipboard with AppleScript. Any ideas? Or perhaps an idea for a solution that doesn't use AppleScript but accomplishes the same thing programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "TextMate" to set x to path of document 1
set the clipboard to x
```

I thought there'd be an environment variable like `TM_CURRENT_LINE` for the contents of the current document, but [apparently not](http://manual.macromates.com/en/environment_variables.html).

Comment: Hi Lri, thanks for the reply. When I put your code into AppleScript Editor and run it (with a TextMate document open), I get the following error: 'tell application "TextMate"
 get path of document 1'
**Result:
error "The variable x is not defined." number -2753 from "x"**

Comment: Was the document the frontmost window / tab? It works both for normal windows and for tabs in project windows for me. Maybe the latter is because I'm using MissingDrawer though.